# Can I print from Ubuntu using a printer installed in Guest OS (Windows XP)?

Tags: virtualbox, printing, canon

I could not make my Canon LBP6000 printer work in ubuntu. I have installed it in my guest os (windows xp) in virtual box. Now I want to use that printer in the guest os from Ubuntu. Is it possible at all? And if yes how?

Thanks

Comment: It depends. How is this printer connected to your computer?. If it is USB, then you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can, there is several ways to do that, over network, or direct.
Here is explanation:http://linuxibos.blogspot.com/2012/05/seprinters-linux.html
On the bottom of that page you can download linux print server which is I think best solution for your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  Its important that you explain your affliation with this link - if its your blog then say so.

Comment: the link is dead.